# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluation 'arrayofServices.reduce)

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, expo

I got a weird error, i created an array of counters to check how many times a service has been booked, when i save and render its works fine. but when im saving again after adding some lines of code the app crashes and i get a Red Error as the title said.

This is the firestore query of getting the services:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).collection("my-appointments").get().then((snapshot) => {
        const arrayOfServices = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            arrayOfServices.push(doc.data().serviceType);
    })
    setServices(arrayOfServices);
    })
}, [])
```

This is the counter array code(duplicate from another page (customized to this page) which working fine!):

```
 const arrayofServices  = services; //services => state the holding the services
    
    const servicesCounter = arrayofServices.reduce((counterObj, service) => {
        if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
          counterObj[service] += 1;
          return counterObj;
        }
      
        return {
          ...counterObj,
          [service]: 1
        };
      }, {});
      setServicesObj(servicesCounter);
      console.log(servicesCounter);
```

Log:

```
Object {
  "Learn JavaScript": 2,
  "Learn React": 1,
  "manicure": 3,
}
```

Comment: maybe the array that you are reducing is undefined

Comment: I have added the log of it, very weird.

Comment: the log is an object not an array, you might have to convert it to an array first, with the logic i gave in one of the previous answers

Comment: to iterate over an object, you could use for..in loop

Answer (score 0):

Before you call .reduce(), add an if statement so your app doesn't crash.

```
if(!arrayOfServices) return;
 const servicesCounter = arrayofServices.reduce((counterObj, service) => {
        if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
          counterObj[service] += 1;
          return counterObj;
        }
      
        return {
          ...counterObj,
          [service]: 1
        };
      }, {});
```

and then, you need to figure it out, why is "arrayOfServices" coming as undefined.

Comment: I cant figure out why, the problem is in the reduce i think. one time its working, one time its not

Comment: The problem is the reduce method because the array that you are trying to reduce is undefined, so you need to check the arrayOfServices.

For example, before setServices(arrayOfServices) you should add console.log(arrayOfServices) to see if it's coming undefined.

Comment: I Managed to deal with it, my partner deleted the docs from the DB